# Trying to understand JavaScript code // Namespaces

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I have a legacy PHP project with lots of JavaScript code that I try to understand.

Each of these JS files start with this code fragment:

```
var myproject = myproject || {};
registerNamespace = function(namespace) {
    var parts = namespace.split(".");
    var root = window;
    for ( var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        if (typeof root[parts[i]] == "undefined") {
            root[parts[i]] = {};
        }
        root = root[parts[i]];
    }
};

registerNamespace('myproject.main');
```

So we create a namespace called myproject in the first line.

The function registerNamespace splits a dot separated string into its parts and adds {part: {}} to the var "root" (which happens to be a copy (or a reference to?) the global namespace of the browser (that is: "window")).

So if a part is not in "root" already (== "undefined"), then we'll add the key/value pair {part: {}} to "root".

Now the thing that I don't understand:
After the if statement we have an assignment that assigns root[parts[i]] to the variable "root" itself. Why?

- In the first iteration of the loop we have parts[i] == "myproject" and root[parts[i]] == {}
- So the assignment is root = {}  ???

What is that last assigment good for?

Also: Is the variable root a reference to the global namespace "window"? So anything I write to "root" will write to "window"? Or is it a copy?

Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`root` is used as a reference.

First, it points to the global 'window' object. If `myproject` is not defined as a property of `window`, `window.myproject` is assigned to a new object.

Then `root` is used to point to the `window.myproject`. If `main` is not defined as a property of `window.myproject`, `window.myproject.main` assigned to a new object.

If the registerNamespace function had been called with, say, the string 'myproject.main.mynamespace', then `root` would have been reassigned to reference `window.myproject.main`, and so on.

```
root = window // root now points to the window object
root['main'] = {} // a new object is created, and root['main'] now points to it
root = root['main'] // root now points to root['main']
```

Comment: So `registerNamespace("myproject.main")`'s first iteration is `root[parts[0]] == {}`, that is `root["myproject"] == {}`, and then `root` is overwritten by {} ?

Comment: `registerNamespace("myproject.main")`'s first iteration is `root[parts[0]] == {}`, that is `root["myproject"] == {}`, and then `root` (which was referencing `window`) is then set to reference `window.myproject` which happens to `== {}`

Comment: And all the while `window` is not overwritten by this? Why did the programmer start by `root = window` anyway? Why not `root = {}`?

Comment: Because `root` is scoped to the registerNamespace function. They want the namespace tree to be a global.